# Upload partial file using form post

Tags: php, post, file-upload

I have an html form where a user can attach a file and upload it to the server. The file can be quite large so I want to be able to read the first line, then respond while parsing the rest of the file in the background, if at all. The point of this whole thing is, they upload a csv. I read the first line, send those columns back to client, and they can link the columns in their file to the standard ones in our database.

1. Upload File
2. Server reads first line before getting rest of file to validate
3. Respond with Json so browser user can link csv columns to db fields
4. Continue file processing while user is linking fields
5. Take user linking and import file

Is it possible without using the HTML5 file API to load a partial or slice of a file from a form submit?